# PromiseKit.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, bundle, code-signing

Until now our project and all associated pods have been in objective c. We wanted to use the latest version of PromiseKit and so added use_frameworks! to our podfile.  Before adding PromiseKit to the PodFile, I confirmed the project runs. After adding PromiseKit to the podfile, I get a 'Command /bin/sh failed with exit code -1' saying 'PromiseKit.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable.'

```
sent 2733061 bytes  received 98 bytes  5466318.00 bytes/sec
total size is 2732456  speedup is 1.00
Code Signing /Users/bryanboyko/XCode/HereOne-iOS/HereOne/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HereOne.app/Frameworks/Parse.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: Bryan Boyko (2J2F768B2X)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 453628556ADD8E5593F102CEF9634DB02042AA98  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements "/Users/bryanboyko/XCode/HereOne-iOS/HereOne/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HereOne.app/Frameworks/Parse.framework"
/Users/bryanboyko/XCode/HereOne-iOS/HereOne/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HereOne.app/Frameworks/Parse.framework: replacing existing signature
rsync -av --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/bryanboyko/XCode/HereOne-iOS/HereOne/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PromiseKit.framework" "/Users/bryanboyko/XCode/HereOne-iOS/HereOne/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HereOne.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
PromiseKit.framework/

sent 102 bytes  received 26 bytes  256.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
Code Signing /Users/bryanboyko/XCode/HereOne-iOS/HereOne/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HereOne.app/Frameworks/PromiseKit.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: Bryan Boyko (2J2F768B2X)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 453628556ADD8E5593F102CEF9634DB02042AA98  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements "/Users/bryanboyko/XCode/HereOne-iOS/HereOne/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HereOne.app/Frameworks/PromiseKit.framework"
/Users/bryanboyko/XCode/HereOne-iOS/HereOne/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HereOne.app/Frameworks/PromiseKit.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

After removing DerivedData, Pods, .xcworkspace, and Podfile.lock, and then pod installing, this error still occurs.

Answer (score 5):

Try `pod deintegrate`, it worked for me to solve weird problems when I was migrating a project to `use_frameworks!`.

```
$ pod deintegrate Project.xcodeproj
$ pod install
```

I have documented the problems I had and how I fixed them [here](https://www.thumbtack.com/engineering/adopting-swift-migrating-frameworks-ios/).

Answer (score 3):

I have the same error by other framework after upgraded to Xcode 8.3.1. Solved by removing `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`