# bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

Xcode:8.1

language:Objective-C

I can run the project on my iPhone, but can't run on the simulator.

I tried:

1)deleting all data of the DerivedData folder

2)cleaning the project and restart the project.

3)deleting the resources folder.

but that didn't work!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38905949/1126520) answer worked for me for cocoapods version - 1.1.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using CocoaPods?
Updating CocoaPods itself + then all the pods worked from me.

Note: this is right after the Xcode autoupdate today.

Comment: Does anyone have an alternative? Updating CocoaPods creates too many issues for me to deal with right now.

Comment: @JoshK have you found any alternative solution ?

Comment: @Bittoo I did! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40481800/project-wont-run-on-simulator-in-xcode-8/40484324#40484324   Although I ended up updating CocoaPods. I highly recommend taking the time to sort it out now. It'll save you from endless headaches in the future.

Answer (score 16):

For those for whom updating Cocoapods or reverting Xcode to 8.0 is not an option, here is a solution that worked for me:

1. Right click on `Pods` in the Project Navigator
2. Click `New File...`
3. Select `Property List`
4. Save the file under the name `Pods-Info.plist` (for example) and leave it empty
5. Select `Pods` in the Project Navigator
6. Select the `Pods` project, then `Build Settings`
7. Search for `Info.plist`
8. Set the value of `Info.plist File` to `Pods-Info.plist`

Comment: Thanks, It worked in my case when upgrading xcode from 8.0 to 8.3.2

Comment: Amazing. Not sure why this does the trick, but also worked for me after upgrading to >=8.1. Thanks alot

Comment: I am not using cocoapod

Comment: Updating the project from 8.0 to 8.3.3 and it worked! Unable to update cocoa pods for the moment, so it is the perfect solution for me.

Comment: Works perfectly!!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. I did the following steps, and it sovled. Select Pods in the navigation --> TARGETS --> your FDTakeResources --> Signing(Enable Development Signing) --> Identity(Choose Info.plist File). Then I can run it on my simulator.

Comment: Pods project is not supposed to be modified.

Comment: @aelam as JoshK said on accepted answer, - Updating cocoaPods creates too many issues for me to deal with right now, so.. this works, and I can move on with my life for now :)

Comment: @GuntisTreulands I'm kinda sure now, you can downgrade your Xcode 8.0-  and it's fine with whatever version of cocoapods. Or you can use Xcode 8.1 + Cocoapods 1.1.1

Comment: @aelam If you also need to work with latest iOS versions (or betas),  downgrading is not an option

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution for topic-starter, however in my case I've recieved this error about 'bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable' during CocoaPods post-build embed frameworks action on attempt to sign any framework. More of that, the issue was reproduced only when running build on Jenkins.

The reason was really stupid. Jenkins was using the custom output directory, which did include space char in the middle. The CP post-build generated script doesn't handle paths with spaces properly, so the codesign tool actually was not fed with the correct path to framework.

SOLUTION: double check you have no spaces in your path :)

Hope this will help somebody to save some time :)

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to watch out for is if something is getting put into the output folder that should not be there or removed from that output folder. For example, in our old builds we put our documentation into the output folder that now gets signed. Now we can't do that, we have to put it alongside the signed output folder. Moving that out solved the unrecognized bundle format error. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a similar issue with CocoaPods 0.39.0, in the end I solved it by modifying my pod spec:

Commenting out

```
s.resource_bundles = {
  'DHSErdi' => ['Pod/Assets/*.png']
}
```

And adding this

```
s.resources = ['Pod/Assets/*.xib', 'Pod/Assets/*.png', 'Pod/Assets/*.jpg', 'Pod/Assets/*.html', 'Pod/Assets/javascript/dist/**/*.js','Pod/Assets/javascript/src/**/*.html']
```